# Understanding the meaning of "DMA" in Linux DMA buf (dmabuf)

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver

I'm seeking clarification regarding the meaning of "DMA" in the context of Linux DMA buf (dmabuf). Does "DMA" in dmabuf directly relate to the hardware DMA peripheral?

Comment: Yes. https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/dma-buf.html Its not spelled out here, but DMA is short for "Direct Memory Access", which is another term that might help to search.

Comment: DMA-capable devices each have their own DMA hardware. Modern computers do not use a shared DMA peripheral such as on early PCs. The dmabuf code defines common scatter-gather and lock code needed by many device drivers.

Comment: Thank you.  The idea is to share memory betwen the different processors in an SoC. One processor runs linux and I would like to develop a kernel driver which would allocate memory from dma buffer and then share this addres to the remote processor over the rpmsg IPC. I could also achieve this via shared memory linux framework instead of the dma buffer framework in the linux

Comment: You will need to ensure coherency and provide a mechanism for synchronization of memory accesses by the different processors. Remember that all addresses in the Linux kernel are virtual.

Comment: @stark "*Modern computers do not use a shared DMA peripheral such as on early PCs*" -- Given the broad spectrum of computers that exist, such a generalization cannot be accurate. The long list of supported DMACs or DMA engines by the Linux kernel (e.g. **drivers/dma/Kconfig**) contradicts your statement. SoCs typically have a "*shared*" system DMAC for low-throughput devices such as UARTs, SPI/TWI/I2C controllers, ADC, and crypto devices. Third-party DMA is far from extinct.

Answer (score 2):

DMA means, that another unit ( not the cpu ) will also access a memory area.
This is normally a pci(e) device.
Every driver for a modern network adapter will use DMA to reduce the CPU load.
The CPU will prepare a ring buffer in memory to transmit data and the NIC will read the next data packet from the memory without CPU usage. For receive a receive ring buffer is prepared by the CPU and the NIC will transfer receive data to the memory and fire a interrupt after receiving a packet.
The memory hast to be DMA coherent. The TLB in the MMU needs a special setup for this memory area.

see:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt